# Consider the space between two strings using awk or any

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to write a bash script where I used awk to get a particular field.

Example:

```
# cat test.txt
USER NAME    LOCATION
Frank        China
Martin       Indonesia
Tom Hanks    United States
Ron Howard   Germany
```

When I tried to take the first field using awk:

```
# cat test.txt  | awk '{print $1}'
USER
Frank
Martin
Tom
Ron
```

But I want output as

**Expected output**

```
#cat test.txt
USER NAME
Frank        
Martin       
Tom Hanks    
Ron Howard
```

I have even tried `awk -F"\t" '{print $1 (or) $2}'`, but I got only the blank output. I'm using this file in a while loop.

```
 #cat test.txt  | awk -F"\t" '{print $2}'
```

Any hint would be helpful.

Comment: It is not possible for `awk -F"\t" '{print $1}` to produce blank output given that input file. Also I recommend you test any proposed solution with the name/country `Ron Hendrick Germany` instead of `Ron Howard   Germany`. You might be surprised...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a delimiter with 2 or more spaces:

```
awk -F ' {2,}' '{print $1}' file

USER NAME
Frank
Martin
Tom Hanks
Ron Howard
```